# VSCode can't setup Java Runtime (tried a few settings json approaches)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed Java via terminal. I am on Linux 5.8.0-53-generic Kubuntu

Java --version outputs

```
openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My VSCode settings point to

```
"java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64"
```

However I get an error saying "The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64) does not point to a JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.home` specifies the folder path to the JDK, which should be like `/usr/java/jdk16`.

Despite manually pointing to the path, we can click it from GUI. Open **Command Palette** and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**. Below the option **Java Tooling Runtime**, the value of `JDK for Language Server` is equal to `java.home`.

[image]

If there's no optional path there, check if you've added java to PATH.

Reference: [Installation of JDK on Linux Platforms.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/install/installation-jdk-linux-platforms.html#GUID-737A84E4-2EFF-4D38-8E60-3E29D1B884B8) and [Using Java runtime configuration wizard](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_using-java-runtime-configuration-wizard).

Comment: I tried adding this to the PATH but it didn't work. 

1) export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH
2) source .bashrc

Still doesn't appear in vscode

Comment: `java.home` points to the jdk installation folder, Is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64` the right path? Try to reinstall another openjdk from the above configuration page and see if it could be displayed correctly. During the installation, don't forget to choose the option: `Add to PATH`.

Comment: I am curious why setting the path myself didnt work when I type is "whereis java" I get 3 places... /user/bin/java .../usr/share/java .../usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Comment: Well I tried installing this via the downloading and installing instructions but doesn't seem to work I pretty much give up on this and will have to just use android studio :(

Comment: Okay update in following the instructions this actually seems to work cause I can run the Java debugger however in the Java Runtime it does not say that JDK is installed. I will mark your reply as the answer. That being said in seeing this on VSCode I am just going to use Android Studio and customize that to be more like VS Code. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Thanks for your mark. If you're going to develop android projects, [Gradle-based Android projects are not supported](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/10#issuecomment-268834749) now. so, it's recommended you use Android Studio for development.

Comment: Gotcha, I am getting more used to it... Changing my code theme to a non stock one (Monokai - my default for 6 years) has helped me enjoy it more :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the required Java version.
Check what is under `/usr/lib/jvm/`

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-java               java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64  java-17-openjdk-amd64  openjdk-17
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-11-openjdk-amd64      openjdk-11
```

Then check in VSCode this settings file:

```
/home/user/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
```

```
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    
    ]
}
```

Change to your JVM version:

```
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    
    ]
}
```

Reload VSCode.